# Javascript - arrayObject rebuilt from looping over mongodb docs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, object

*Am rebuilding an arrayObject by looping over elements from an ajax .get of the MongoDB docs..*

**The arrayObject is almost proper, but it's missing comma separation between docs in the array.**

It SEEMS this is why `console.log(arrayObject[0].name);` is `undefined`

But trying an if/else statement, to exclude a preceding comma at the start, skips the `if`

```
function reBuild(returnValue)
{
  var docs = returnValue;
  var returnedVal = [];
  for (var i=0, length=docs.length; i < length; i++){

    if (returnedVal === [])
    {
      returnedVal.push('{' + 'title: "' + docs[i].title + '", quantity: ' + docs[i].quantity + ', _id: "' + docs[i]._id + '"}');
    }
    else
    {
      returnedVal.push(', {' + 'title: "' + docs[i].title + '", quantity: ' + docs[i].quantity + ', _id: "' + docs[i]._id + '"}');
    }

    console.log(returnedVal[i]);

  }
  console.log(returnedVal[0].title);
}
```

console.log(returnedVal[i]);

```
[15:20:02.946] "{title: "Sample1", value: 2, _id: "530c12c66e6b0de318000001"}"
[15:20:02.946] ", {title: "Sample2", value: 4, _id: "530c12cc6e6b0de318000002"}"
```

MongoDB via .get:

```
function getAll(res) {

    db.collection('demo').find().sort( { value: 1 } ).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        console.log("Got the Docs: " + utils.inspect(docs));

        // each doc looks like: { _id: ObjectID, title: 'string', quantity: int}

        res.json({docs: docs});

    });
}
```

Docs looks like this in the terminal console:

```
[ { _id: 530c12c66e6b0de318000001,
    title: 'Sample1',
    quantity: 2 },
  { title: 'Sample2',
    quantity: 4,
    _id: 530c12cc6e6b0de318000002 } ]
```

*Am looking to .get an `arrayObject` of MongoDB docs, build `var` from the arrayObject using `object.foo`, and then reBuild an `arrayObject` of the all the foobar, once ranked..*

Have another function that handles some variable calculations for ranking.

Comment: we don't need to manage the array - `returnedVal.push(',` just `.push(..` is fine. remove that comma and all will be well

Comment: Why are you putting hand-built (invalid) JSON strings into an array?  Why not create an array of object literals, then `JSON.stringify` (and/or `.join()`) it?

Comment: so, please widen the code you are using- eg provide and example of the data for `returnValue` and we will see what's happening.

Comment: basically, there's another function that is going to loop over the arrayObject to change values and ranking order.. The doc then needs to be rebuilt to loop through for building some custom html

Comment: @RobSedgwick added more code, now more transparent

Comment: @RocketHazmat could you provide an example of what the object literals to JSON.stringify would look like? Thanks

Comment: yeah, you have quite a bit going on here , will throw in an answer to explain.

Comment: @RobSedgwick Thanks!! Originally was without the if/else, and no comma, but console.log(returnedVal[0].title); was logging undefined, so I thought the comma separation might have been the issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As the update**

Given the data `returnValue` being *( as your example )*

```
[ 
  { _id: 530c12c66e6b0de318000001,title:'Sample1', quantity: 2 },
  { _id: 530c12cc6e6b0de318000002, title:'Sample2', quantity:4} 
]
```

being passed to your `reBuild()` function `reBuild(returnValue)`

'reBuild()' being the function to recreate the 'returnValue' format into another array:

**Your example ..**

```
 returnedVal.push(', {' + 'title: "' ...
```

**... has a number of issues**, - the leading comma being sent to the `push` method and the closing and unclosing of quotes to create strings or a form of custom [json](http://json.org/)

**Lets simplify that function to**

```
function reBuild(arr) {

 var returnedVal = [];
 for (var i=0, len=returnValue.length; i < len; ++i){
   var newval = {_id:arr[i]._id,title:arr[i].title,quantity:arr.arr[i].quantity};
   returnedVal.push(newvalue);
 }

 console.log(returnedVal);
 return (returnedVal);

}
```

**It works, but what did we do ? - absolutely nothing**. All we did was take an array `returnedVal` *( I shortened the name to `arr` for the example)* and rebuilt it exactly the same.

Lets look at the ajax data request, you gave

```
db.collection('demo').find().sort( { value: 1 } ).toArray(function (err, docs) {
    console.log("Got the Docs: " + utils.inspect(docs));
    res.json({docs: docs});

});
```

I guess we are missing the part where the rebuild() function hooks up ?

Looking at the `res.json({docs: docs});` part of it- (a function to respond with data as json ), would this the correct flow ?..

```
db.collection('demo').find().sort( { value: 1 } ).toArray(function (err, docs) {

    /* pass and rebuild the data array before you 'json' it */
    var rebuiltDocs = reBuild(docs); 
    res.json({docs: rebuiltDocs});

});
```

---

I have guessed at a number of things here to what your app is doing. But the key part is understanding that once you [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) you are looking at a string representation of your javascript object.

If you require `JSON` to transport the data over http ( the main reason for it ) then do your routines on the data before you 'jsonify' it.

To unJSON data use `JSON.parse(docs)`

- For Data **within your application** ( if arriving as json ) use
  `JSON.parse()`
- **To transport data between systems** use `JSON.stringify()`

---

I don't feel like I have helped here, but hopefully went some way to explain how and why you may have felt the need to hard craft some of those arrays.

Comment: oh , that was lucky :) which bit helped ?

Comment: simplifying that function did wonders. and passing the data array through node is also really great.. for whatever reason though, the inclusion of the function call does something weird with the ajax. the .get seems to remain open, such that a      `$('#retrieve').html(html);` on a `btn.click` does not replace the html, it adds to it! `GET http://localhost:9999/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 10ms]` isn't called for each click, more divs log